Guitarix hangs on the first screen of the presentation
I’m trying out the Ubuntu Studio 24.04 live. Ccurrently I have 22.04 installed, and before updating I want to make sure that the system responds reliably. When I start Guitarix the program hangs on the first screen of the presentation, and from there it goes no further and I have to stop it.
Other similar programs (Rakarrack, for example) start and appear in the links.
I'm running Ubuntu on a laptop with an Intel (R) Core (TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz and with 6GB of RAM.
I misspoke, and I apologize. When I start Guitarix (which freezes immediately) does not appear on the connections of Jack*, unlike other programs like Rakarrack that start normally and are included in the above mentioned connections.

For now I'm referring to Jack: I'm still studying for Pipewire, although I think I've understood that it's an "entity" in the background.

This is all that appears when I start Guitarix.

These are the links of Jack after starting Guitarix and Rakarrack.

This is what comes out:
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ guitarix
(guitarix:5941): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:03:33.168: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
(guitarix:5941): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:03:33.168: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field

I took a look at the file called and compared it with that of version 22.04, and they are the same.
I don't know if it can be useful:
I also tried to prepend sudo and the following message came out.
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ sudo guitarix
can't create guitarix config dir '/root/.config/guitarix/'

But as far as I know the directory '.config' is in home (where actually also subtendeva the directory guitarix) and not in root.

"Other similar programs [...] appear in the links" - you mean in the dock? So Guitarix doesn't even appear in the dock?

I aswer editing my question

It works for me on GNOME / 24.04. What happens if you run guitarix on the terminal? Could you please post the terminal output so that we can look at it?

I have further modified my application by adding the requested

The GTK messages are just warnings, so I suppose those wouldn't be indicative  of the issue... Sorry, I don't know exactly what to suggest, personally I'd try and install everything in a VM  (say Virtualbox - with guest additions as well) and see if it works. Perhaps it's just an issue with the Live.

Yes, I thought so too, but for now unless I come into my hands a disk on which to install it I will go ahead with the 22.04. Thank you and, as soon as I update to 24.04 I will let you know. I take advantage of it: do you use guitarix? Do I have to open another instance to ask you for information or can I continue here?

I don't use guitarix, sorry! I just thought I could help in diagnosing the issue. You can also try and install it in a VM (using Virtualbox or similar) without having to resort to use a physical drive. Ok, let me know how it fares! You can ping me with @kos, so far I've been notified of your comments because nobody else replied, but if someone else replies I won't see your comments anymore unless you add @kos in your comment
